# how can I improve the look and impact of thi tikz tree diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

% styles for flowcharts
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.6cm, auto, >=stealth]
   % nodes
   \node[block](Physiological Reflux)[0,0]{Physiological Reflux};
   \node[block] (Symptomatic GERD)  [right of=Physiological Reflux]                       {Symptomatic GERD};
   \node[block,text width=2.8cm]
                (Esophagitis)  [right of=Symptomatic GERD, node distance=3.3cm]  {Esophagitis};
   \node[block] (Complicated GERD)  [right of=Esophagitis, node distance=3.6cm]  {Complicated GERD};
   \node[block, textwidth=4cm] (Typical)  [below left of=Symptomatic GERD, node distance=4cm]    {{\bf Typical} \newline Heart burn \\  Regurgitation};
   \node[block](Atypical)[below right of=Symptomatic GERD, node distance =4cm]{{\bf atypical}\\ \indent Chest pain\\dysphagia\\Cough \\ Asthma \\ Laryngitis  };
    \node [block](Complicated)[below  of =Complicated GERD, node distance =4cm]{ {\bf Complicated }\\Ulcerations\\ Hemorrhages \\ Barret's esophagus \\ Stricture\\ Adenocarcinoma };
   % edges
  \draw[->] (Physiological Reflux) -- (Symptomatic GERD);
  \draw[->] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Esophagitis);
   \draw[->] (Esophagitis) -- (Complicated GERD);
   \draw[->] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Typical);
   \draw[->] (Symptomatic GERD)--  (Atypical);
    \draw[->](Complicated GERD)--(Complicated);
   %\draw[->] (e) -- (f);
   %\draw[->] (f) -- (g);
   %\draw[->] (g) -- (h);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What, specifically, would you like to improve? Please add more details about what you'd like to achieve and perhaps an image showing the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

1. I added some color (that's optional).
2. I changed from the deprecated `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset`.
3. I scaled down a little bit the figure.
4. The most important change was the use of the `positioning` library and the change from the deprecated `of =` syntax to the more appropriate `= of` (this allows for a better positioning of the nodes).

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

% styles for flowcharts
\tikzset{
block/.style = {
  rectangle,
  thick,
  text width=6em,
  align=center,
  rounded corners,
  draw=cyan!40!black,
  fill=cyan!20,
  inner ysep=10pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 2cm and 0.8cm,
  >=stealth,
  scale=0.8,
  transform shape
]
% nodes
\node[block] 
  (Physiological Reflux) {Physiological Reflux};
\node[block,right = of Physiological Reflux] 
  (Symptomatic GERD) {Symptomatic GERD};
\node[block,right = of Symptomatic GERD]
  (Esophagitis) {Esophagitis};
\node[block,right = of Esophagitis] 
  (Complicated GERD) {Complicated GERD};
\node[block,below=of Symptomatic GERD,xshift=-2cm] 
  (Typical) {{\bfseries Typical} \\ Heart burn \\  Regurgitation};
\node[block,below=of Symptomatic GERD,xshift=2cm]
  (Atypical) {{\bfseries Atypical}\\ Chest pain\\dysphagia\\Cough \\ Asthma \\ Laryngitis};
\node[block,below = of Complicated GERD,text width=8em] 
  (Complicated) {{\bfseries Complicated }\\Ulcerations\\ Hemorrhages \\ Barret's esophagus \\ Stricture\\ Adenocarcinoma };

% edges
\begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
\draw[->] (Physiological Reflux) -- (Symptomatic GERD);
\draw[->] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Esophagitis);
\draw[->] (Esophagitis) -- (Complicated GERD);
\draw[->] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Typical);
\draw[->] (Symptomatic GERD)--  (Atypical);
\draw[->](Complicated GERD)--(Complicated);
%\draw[->] (e) -- (f);
%\draw[->] (f) -- (g);
%\draw[->] (g) -- (h);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `\bf` is an old TeX command that shouldn't be used in modern LaTeX documents; use `\bfseries` instead.

Another change that might result handy is to use overlays to uncover the figure on several slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

% style for overlays
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}

% styles for flowcharts
\tikzset{
block/.style = {
  rectangle,
  thick,
  text width=6em,
  align=center,
  rounded corners,
  draw=cyan!40!black,
  fill=cyan!20,
  inner ysep=10pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 2cm and 0.8cm,
  >=stealth,
  scale=0.8,
  transform shape
]
% nodes
\node[block,visible on=<1->] 
  (Physiological Reflux) {Physiological Reflux};
\node[block,right = of Physiological Reflux,visible on=<2->] 
  (Symptomatic GERD) {Symptomatic GERD};
\node[block,right = of Symptomatic GERD,visible on=<5->]
  (Esophagitis) {Esophagitis};
\node[block,right = of Esophagitis,visible on=<6->] 
  (Complicated GERD) {Complicated GERD};
\node[block,below=of Symptomatic GERD,xshift=-2cm,visible on=<3->] 
  (Typical) {{\bfseries Typical} \\ Heart burn \\  Regurgitation};
\node[block,below=of Symptomatic GERD,xshift=2cm,visible on=<4->]
  (Atypical) {{\bfseries Atypical}\\ Chest pain\\dysphagia\\Cough \\ Asthma \\ Laryngitis};
\node[block,below = of Complicated GERD,text width=8em,visible on=<7>] 
  (Complicated) {{\bfseries Complicated }\\Ulcerations\\ Hemorrhages \\ Barret's esophagus \\ Stricture\\ Adenocarcinoma };

% edges
\begin{scope}[cyan!40!black]
\draw[->,visible on=<2->] (Physiological Reflux) -- (Symptomatic GERD);
\draw[->,visible on=<5->] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Esophagitis);
\draw[->,visible on=<6->] (Esophagitis) -- (Complicated GERD);
\draw[->,visible on=<3->] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Typical);
\draw[->,visible on=<4->] (Symptomatic GERD)--  (Atypical);
\draw[->,visible on=<7->](Complicated GERD)--(Complicated);
%\draw[->] (e) -- (f);
%\draw[->] (f) -- (g);
%\draw[->] (g) -- (h);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on Gonzalo's code. I think `scale=0.8, transform shape` is not necessary. It's possible to modify `node distance` and to use `font`. With pgf 3 it's possible to use `node font`. Then it's not necessary to use `text width`and we can avoid the last scope

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

% styles for flowcharts
\tikzset{
block/.style = {
  rectangle,
  thick,
  align=center,
  rounded corners,
  draw=cyan!40!black,
  fill=cyan!20,
  inner ysep=10pt
  },
  ar/.style = {cyan!40!black,->}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 1.75 cm and 0.75cm,font=\tiny,
  >=stealth
]
% nodes
\node[block] 
  (Physiological Reflux) {Physiological Reflux};
\node[block,right = of Physiological Reflux] 
  (Symptomatic GERD) {Symptomatic GERD};
\node[block,right = of Symptomatic GERD]
  (Esophagitis) {Esophagitis};
\node[block,right = of Esophagitis] 
  (Complicated GERD) {Complicated GERD};
\node[block,below=of Symptomatic GERD,xshift=-1.75cm] 
  (Typical) {{\bfseries Typical} \\ Heart burn \\  Regurgitation};
\node[block,below=of Symptomatic GERD,xshift=1.75cm]
  (Atypical) {{\bfseries Atypical}\\ Chest pain\\dysphagia\\Cough \\ Asthma \\ Laryngitis};
\node[block,below = of Complicated GERD] 
  (Complicated) {{\bfseries Complicated }\\Ulcerations\\ Hemorrhages \\ Barret's esophagus \\ Stricture\\ Adenocarcinoma };

% edges
\draw[ar] (Physiological Reflux) -- (Symptomatic GERD);
\draw[ar] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Esophagitis);
\draw[ar] (Esophagitis) -- (Complicated GERD);
\draw[ar] (Symptomatic GERD) -- (Typical);
\draw[ar] (Symptomatic GERD) --  (Atypical);
\draw[ar] (Complicated GERD)--(Complicated);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo what is stealth